# Modal doesn't work with LayoutAnimation on iPhone

Tags: react-native

This is what I'm trying to do, basically, click `Open Modal` button to open modal, then click `Close Modal` button inside modal to close it. The two pictures below are how both cases should look like.

This is my code:

```
    export default class App extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                showModal: false
            };
        }

        componentWillUpdate() {
            if(PlatForm.OS === 'android') {
               UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental(true);
            }
            LayoutAnimation.easeInEaseOut();
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <View style={{ ... }}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({ showModal: true })}>
                        <Text style={{ ... }}>
                            Open Modal
                        </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <Modal visible={this.state.showModal} animationType='slide'>
                        <View style={{ ... }}>
                            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({ showModal: false })}>
                                <Text style={{ color: 'white', fontSize: 20 }}>
                                    Close Modal
                                </Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
                    </Modal>
                </View>
            );
        }
    }
```

Everything works as expected when running on an IOS simulator, but problems rises when running on an iPhone. When press `Close Modal`, modal disappears for like half a second, then reopens itself again, and this time, `Close Modal` button won't work, I cannot re-close modal. All I can do is to re-build project. However, when I delete `componentWillUpdate()`, it works again, both on simulator and on iPhone

[image: When modal is closed]

[image: When modal is open]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is a bug introduced in a recent version of React Native. Your best bet, for now, is to disable LayoutAnimation. Not ideal...I know.

See the discussion on Github here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/16182